# My javascript module is not working, erroring with undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a js file that has the following:

```
;
var tracker = (function () {

    var _track = function(userId, atts) {
        alert(userId);
    };


    return {
        track: function (userId, atts) {
            _track(userId, atts);
        }
    }
}());
```

I am loading the javascript using the pattern I see other services doing:

```
<script>
(function(w, d, js) {
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
        s = d.createElement('script');
    s.async = true;
    s.src = js;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(s, f);
})(window, document, '//localhost/WebApp1/Assets/tracker/tracker.js');

var userAtts = {
        'foo': 1,
        'bar': 2,
        'some-invalid-identifier': 3
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        tracker.track(3213, userAtts);
    });
</script>
```

I get this error:

```
(index):107 Uncaught ReferenceError: tracker is not defined.
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Comment: where is the tracker definition?

Comment: do you include `js.js` before `<script>var userAtts = {...`?

Comment: Yes js.js is before I call it.

Comment: What's with the three dots in this path: `.../js.js`, maybe it's something I've never heard of, but I think you may be getting the path wrong.

Comment: @DBS I updated my question, sorry I am loading it in a asych fashion.  I added the script tag just to debug something sorry.

Comment: Ah, well it's an async call, you're using `tracker` before the external JS has finished being added.

Comment: I think you have a timing issue here. $(document).ready is firing before your tracker is defined. I loaded your definition for tracker in the head of the document for troubleshooting purposes and it started working.  I don't think $(document).ready is going to wait for your scripts to be fully loaded, especially if you are loading async.

Comment: I wonder what snowplow does, I guess internally they check for doc loaded. https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow-javascript-tracker/tree/b6e65b0bb544909c914c9cfdfdd34c3288a75608

Comment: @coolbreeze, if you see loading script for this lib, you can find `p[i]=function(){...}` so, here init global variable that name you pass, so you can use it right after iife run

Comment: @coolbreeze, also name for this variable save in `GlobalSnowplowNamespace`, so script that loaded know where find it. that's why they not use `onload` handler

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the external JS is loaded before attempting to use the `tracker` function.

One ultra simple way would be to just keep trying until tracker is created:

```
var trackerLoadedListener = setInterval(function(){
  if (typeof tracker !== 'undefined'){
    clearInterval(trackerLoadedListener);
    // Your function call / code here, should only execute once tracker is available
  }
}, 500)
```

Alternatively you could write a callback from the function that adds the script. However I don't know whether there's any delay between the script being added and it being processed/use-able within your code.

Comment: I'll leave this here for reference, but Grundy's http://stackoverflow.com/a/36339767/1650337 is a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way calling `tracker` when script is loaded add handler to *onload* event, and pass this directly, or use *promises*.

For example:

```
var trackerPromise = (function(w, d, js) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
      s = d.createElement('script');  
    s.async = true;
    s.src = js;
    s.onload = resolve;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(s, f);

  });
})(window, document, 'script.js');
```

and use this instead jQuery `ready` function

```
trackerPromise.then(function() {
  tracker.track(3213, userAtts);
});
```

[**Sample plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/O935nqmPDrMHh1JqQU1y?p=preview)